# Undefined method 'host' in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following methods in a Ruby script:

```
def parse_endpoint(endpoint)
    return URI.parse(endpoint) 
end 

def verify_url(endpoint, fname)
    url = “#{endpoint}#{fname}” 
    req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)     
    res = req.request_head(url.path) 
    if res.code == “200” 
        true 
    else 
        puts “#{fname} is an invalid file” 
        false
    end 
end
```

Testing the url manually like so works fine (returns true since the url is indeed valid):

```
endpoint = parse_endpoint('http://mywebsite.com/mySubdirectory/')
verify_url(endpoint, “myFile.json”)
```

However, when I try to do the following in rspec

```
describe 'my functionality' 

    let (:endpoint) { parse_endpoint(“http://mywebsite.com/mySubdirectory/”) } 

    it 'should verify valid url' do 
        expect(verify_url(endpoint, “myFile.json”).to eq(true))
    end 
end
```

it gives me this error

```
“NoMethodError:
undefined method `host' for "http://mysebsite.com/mySubdirectory/myFile.json":String”
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

url is a `String` object, and you are trying to access a method called `host` which does not exist in `String`:

```
url = “#{endpoint}#{fname}” 
req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
```

**EDIT** you probably need an URI object. I think this is what you want:

```
2.2.1 :004 > require 'uri'
 => true 
2.2.1 :001 > url = 'http://mywebsite.com/mySubdirectory/'
 => "http://mywebsite.com/mySubdirectory/" 
2.2.1 :005 > parsed_url = URI.parse url
 => #<URI::HTTP http://mywebsite.com/mySubdirectory/> 
2.2.1 :006 > parsed_url.host
 => "mywebsite.com"
```

So just add `url = URI.parse url` before using `url.host`.

Comment: That identifies the problem but not the solution. What about `URI.parse`?

Comment: @tadman Yes, URI has a 'host' method. I edited my answer explaining how to solve the problem using URI.

Comment: That's exactly what the answer needed. Nice! Worth noting that `URI.parse` can throw exceptions, so be prepared for the unexpected in production code.

Answer (score 1):

> Testing the url manually like so works fine (returns true since the url is indeed valid):
>
> ```
> endpoint = parse_endpoint('http://mywebsite.com/mySubdirectory/')
> verify_url(endpoint, “myFile.json”)
> ```

It seems you missed something when you tested code above (maybe you tested old version) because it can't work as it is now.

Look at these lines of code:

```
url = "#{endpoint}#{fname}"
req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
```

You're creating a string variable `url` from other two variables `endpoint` and `fname`. So far, so good.

But then you're trying to access method `host` on `url` variable, which doesn't exist (but it exists on the `endpoint` variable), that's why you get this error.

You may want to use this code instead:

```
def verify_url(endpoint, fname)
  url = endpoint.merge(fname)
  res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
    http.head(url.path)
  end
  # it's actually a bad idea to puts some text in a query method
  # let's just return value instead
  res.code == "200"
end
```